# LINQ Distinct Count returns 1

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Im making a delegate Func inside my method to check if **schedualCode** fits in a certain place in a list, where the limit is 3.
i want to count the distinct values of schedualCode in my list. my problem is that schedualCodeCount returns 1. when it should return 2.
this is my code

```
        Func<string, bool> CheckTimeLimit = delegate (string schedualCode)
        {
            // check enrolled period count (where limit is 3) 
            //int periodCount = currentEnrollments.GroupBy(t => t.Times)
            //.Select(t => t.Key.Select(key => key.PeriodCode == time.PeriodCode).Distinct()).Count();
            var allTimes = currentEnrollments.SelectMany(key => key.Times).ToList();

            List<string> schedualCodes = allTimes.Where(key => key.SchedualCode == schedualCode && key.ViewOnSchedual)
                                                 .Select(key => key.SchedualCode).ToList();

            //schedualCodes List returns a list of count = 2 , and 2 strings exactly the same of value  = "A1"


            // Getting the distinct count of "A1"
            int schedualCodeCount = schedualCodes.Distinct().Count();
            // schedualCodeCount gets the value = 1, where it should be 2 

            // time fits if true
            return schedualCodeCount < 3;
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what Distinct does. You have two identical items, Distinct will remove the duplicates leaving you with 1. What you probably want to do is Group and then get the counts of each group.

For example:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "A1", "A1" };

Console.WriteLine(list.Count);         // 2, obviously

var distinct = list.Distinct();        // select only the *distinct* values
Console.WriteLine(distinct.Count());   // 1 - because there is only 1 distinct value

var groups = list.GroupBy(s => s);     // group your list (there will only be one
                                       // in this case)

foreach (var g in groups)              // for each group
{
    // Display the number of items with the same key
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key + ":" + g.Count());   
}
```